# Does PyTorch seed affect dropout layers?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, pytorch, random-seed

I came across the idea of seeding my neural network for reproducible results, and was wondering if pytorch seeding affects dropout layers and what is the proper way to seed my training/testing?

I'm reading the documentation [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/cuda.html?highlight=manual_seed_all#torch.cuda.manual_seed), and wondering if just placing these lines will be enough?

```
torch.manual_seed(1)
torch.cuda.manual_seed(1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily answer your question with some lines of code:

```
import torch
from torch import nn

dropout = nn.Dropout(0.5)
torch.manual_seed(9999)
a = dropout(torch.ones(1000))
torch.manual_seed(9999)
b = dropout(torch.ones(1000))
print(sum(abs(a - b)))
# > tensor(0.)
```

Yes, using `manual_seed` is enough.

Comment: What about dropout across hardware?

Answer (score 1):

Actually it depends on your device:

If cpu:

- `torch.manual_seed(1) == true`.

If cuda:

- `torch.cuda.manual_seed(1)=true`
- `torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True`

Lastly, use the following code can make sure the results are reproducible among python, numpy and pytorch.

```cpp
def setup_seed(seed):
    random.seed(seed)                          
    numpy.random.seed(seed)                       
    torch.manual_seed(seed)                    
    torch.cuda.manual_seed(seed)               
    torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed)           
    torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True  


setup_seed(42)
```